# Probability including downtime between events

Tags: probability

## Background

I was trying to figure out how many meteor defenses I 'needed' in the Factorio Space Exploration mod, and realized that I have forgotten much of basic probability. I ended up doing a Monte-Carlo sim to approximate the answer, but I'd like to know how to answer this analytically if possible.

## Actual Problem

When a meteor swarm occurs, a random number of meteors appear. 50% chance of one meteor, 25% chance of 2, 12.5% chance of 3, and so on.

A meteor swarm occurs 1-30 minutes after the previous swarm, inclusive of both endpoints. (Technically this is discrete, with 60 game ticks / second, but I believe you can neglect this.)

A single meteor defense fires one shot, with an 80% probability of hitting and destroying a single meteor (the other 20% missing).

(To be clear: there's no aiming or anything here. It's as though the defenses were lined up and taking shots one at a time. So if e.g. I have two defenses and two incoming meteors, I have a 64% chance of both being destroyed, a 4% chance of neither being destroyed, and a 32% chance of one being destroyed.)

Once a meteor defense takes a shot, it then takes 2 minutes to recharge. Note that this is greater than the minimum time between swarms.

If I have N meteor defenses, how often on average will pass between meteor(s) getting through the defenses?

## Where I Get Stuck

I found it fairly straightforward to calculate the answer if you ignore the recharge time of the meteor defenses, through... call it brute force and ignorance. (Well, a Python script and `import fractions`. So same difference.) Calculate the full (binomial) hit distribution of the meteor defenses, and sum P(n meteors) * P(defenses could shoot down at least n meteors) over all n. This gives P(defenses successfully defend against a swarm), which can then be turned into the desired result fairly easily.

Where I get stuck is trying to include the recharge time of the meteor defenses. I don't really know where to begin, aside from a nagging memory that this might be related somehow to Markov chains.

Comment: My apologies for the terrible title. I don't really know how to phrase it.

Comment: As an aside, if this looks very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447120/how-much-redundancy-is-needed-to-comfortably-ensure-an-outcome-of-a-probabilisti that's because it is. Said other question is about the same mod, but neglects the hard part that I'm confused about.